# ggplot2: How to summarize count? stat_summary or stat_bin

Tags: r, plot, count, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 to just count and summarize the number of occurrences of each mode in my data frame. testdata$V5 is a factor with 4 different modes. Every line in testdata has an entry for mode and I want to count them.

```
p <- ggplot(testdata,aes(V5))
p = p + geom_histogram()
show(p)
```

This code produces the following plot:

[image: produced plot]

I am now trying to show text labels on top of each bar plot that show the count but I can't quite understand how to achieve that using stat_summary. How can I produce a text label at the top of each x value bar showing the count?

I tried

```
p <- ggplot(testdata,aes(V5))
p = p + geom_histogram()
p = p + stat_summary(fun.data=count, geom="text", size=20, color="red") #<-- no effect
show(p)
```

but it doesn't draw anything.

Comment: `geom_histogram` uses `stat_bin` and not `stat_summary`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a "hidden" variable `..count..` in conjunction with `geom_text`:

```
p + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  stat_bin(aes(label=..count..), geom="text", position="identity", size=20, color="red")
```

`geom_text` also has `hjust` and `vjust` parameters that may be helpful.

Comment: I so needed this with `geom="text` and `position="identity"` . . . I did not know how to just echo the existing count and it should be easy like this!  So many other answers are saying to pre-calculate it which I would greatly rather avoid.